# Merging several PDFs using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I found this [link](https://github.com/GowenGit/docnet).

I would like to merge several pdfs into one

My question how can I do the same with LINQ?

```
if (pdfFileContentBytes.Length >=2)
{
    byte[] a = pdfFileContentBytes[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < pdfFileContentBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        using (var library = DocLib.Instance)
        {
            byte[] b = pdfFileContentBytes[i];
            byte[] temp = a;

           a = library.Merge(temp, b);
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("myfile4.pdf", a);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: using (var library = DocLib.Instance)
                    {
                         var res=library.Merge(pdfFileContentBytes[0], pdfFileContentBytes[1]);
                         
                    }

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US, we are sensitive.

Comment: so i am sorry for shouting out

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pdfFileContentBytes.Length >=2)
{
      var a = pdfFileContentBytes[0];

         using (DocLib.Instance)
            pdfFileContentBytes.Skip(1).ForEach(b => a= 
        DocLib.Instance.Merge(a,b));
     return a
}
```